# How to secure API keys from being stolen when making remote calls

Tags: security, architecture, password-encryption, api-key

We have api_key, api_secret for accessing various external services. This is the current architecture/model.

users (id, email ...)
user_service_configs (id, user_id, api_key, api_secret)

Standalone application calls a standalone service running on same machine and passes (user_id, api_key, api_secret) on the wire. 
The standalone service makes a remote call to external service using the passed in information.
The key/secret values are user specific, so it would differ for everyone.
I would want to avoid someone snooping on these values and stealing them.

What would be the ideal design to manage these api_key/secret(s). Should I just pass the user_id and do a database lookup on the server to fetch api_key/secret(s) or what else can I do to make this secure.

Answer (score 0):

To address the primary question in your title "How to secure API keys from being stolen when making remote calls" I would recommend use of TLS/SSL. An HTTPS connection to the remote service will ensure that any sensitive data such as API keys passed over the wire are encrypted end-to-end. This will protect from man-in-the-middle style attacks where a malicious user may have access to the wire.

I'm afraid I don't understand enough about your architecture to help further in regards to management of API keys/secrets.

Comment: The remote service is not owned by us and some of them are still unsecure, this is something which I cannot control. I am looking to figure out how to manage keys within the application environment

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly your concern is more about protecting the API keys/secrets stored on the machine hosting the standalone application and service. Can you shed more detail in your question about the environment? For example is this a Windows/Linux server environment, or mobile application? It sounds like the API keys/secrets are stored in a database right now per user. Where is this database located?

Comment: The MySQL database is hosted in a RDS instance. The server(s) run in a Linux AMI based EC2 instances. Currently the api keys are stored in plain text in a certain table.